# How to manage downloading data in ionic 2

Tags: download, ionic2, load

I have small issue with managing the downloading data of firebase to my ionic application.

For example: In the normal case [such as below code], the downloading data is normal [such as this image]

[image]

```
constructor(...){
    this.questionsList = this.afd.list('/questions/');
}
```

But if I used "setInterval" [such as below code], the downloading of data increase [such as this image]

[image]

```
constructor(...){
    this.questionsList = this.afd.list('/questions/');
    this.favoritesList = this.afd.list('/favorites/',{
        query:{
            orderByChild:'user_id',
            equalTo: userService.id,
        }
    })

    this.joinObjects();
    this.refreshIntervalId=setInterval(()=>{
        this.joinObjects();
    },250);
}

joinObjects(){
    let TempListX=[];
    this.favoritesList.take(1).subscribe(data1=>{
        this.questionsList.take(1).subscribe(data2=>{
            TempListX = data1.slice(0);
            for(let i=0; i<data1.length; i++){
                for(let j=0; j<data2.length; j++){
                    if(data1[i].question_id==data2[j].$key){
                        TempListX[i].qTitle=data2[j].title;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (JSON.stringify(TempListX)===JSON.stringify(this.TempFavoritesList)) {
            }else{
                this.TempFavoritesList=TempListX.slice();
            }
        })
    })
}
```

So is there any way to make the downloading data be such as normal case ?

Comment: Just to be sure: You are asking why there is higher network activity if you fetch something from firebase every 250ms vs. when you fetch it once?!

Comment: Yes.. I don't know why when I used "subscribe" to make a new array the usage of network increased .. Still I don't know how can I solve this problem

Comment: Because by subscribing to the firebase observables you are fetching the data every time you call your method.

Comment: @David so is there any solutions for this problem to reduced the usage of my network ?

Comment: Yes, don't call `.subscribe()` every 250ms. You should read some basic tutorials regarding observables and firebase, otherwise you will run into a lot of problems.

Comment: @David thanks, I changed the value of refresh to 7500.. its reduced the usage of network but if u know any batter solutions, I will be happy if u edit my code and solve my issue (if u can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested here is a refactored version of your code. I have to say I did not test it but it should outline the concept. The method `joinObjects()` is called every time an updated value/list arrives and not in a fixed interval which creates a lot of overhead. Notice the new instance variables I added and that I renamed your observables to `favoritesList$` and `questionsList$` (the dollar suffix is good practice to indicate that it is an observable (not a subscription, value, ...).

```
public questions;
public favorites;

constructor(...) {
  this.questionsList$ = this.afd.list('/questions/');
  this.favoritesList$ = this.afd.list('/favorites/', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'user_id',
      equalTo: userService.id,
    },
  });

  this.questionsList$.subscribe(updatedList => {
    this.questions = updatedList;
    this.joinObjects();
  });

  this.favoritesList$.subscribe(updatedList => {
    this.favorites = updatedList;
    this.joinObjects();
  });
}

joinObjects() {
  let TempListX = [];
  TempListX = this.questions.slice(0);
  for (let i = 0; i < this.questions.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.favorites.length; j++) {
      if (this.questions[i].question_id == this.favorites[j].$key) {
        TempListX[i].qTitle = this.favorites[j].title;
      }
    }
  }
  if (JSON.stringify(TempListX) === JSON.stringify(this.TempFavoritesList)) {
  } else {
    this.TempFavoritesList = TempListX.slice();
  }
}
```

I hope this brings you closer to your goal!

Comment: Thank u v.much, now I understood the idea... because I read some tutorials but I didn't understand this point v.well .. 

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out!